# Naoqi pepper python SDK

Tags: python, sdk, pepper

I am trying to call an animation package using choreograph pepper simulation through python from their SDK files. I have not had any trouble using the regular motion and speak proxies, however I can't seem to get the animations working. Here is the code.

```
 animation_player_service = ALProxy("ALAnimationPlayer", "127.0.0.1",9559)
 future=animation_player_service.run("Animation/Moods/Positive/Pepper/Happy",_async=True)
 future.value()
```

Every time I run the code it says "RuntimeError:    ALAnimationPlayer::run
Wrong path format (Animation/Moods/Positive/Pepper/Happy) which has been converted in: Animation/Moods/Positive/Pepper/Happy, it should follow the pattern: package/path" I'm using the format it says on their website, so I am not sure why I am getting this error. Ive also tried copying the exact path from my computer and pasting it into the animation_player_service.run(), and have also changed the / to \ since paths in window have that syntax. I would appreciate any advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Animations are actually behaviors installed in the package `animations`. You can list all installed standard animations by running `find /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/animations -name behavior.xar` in the robot shell.

A correct path to the ALAnimationPlayer call is then the directory including the `animations` package name (but without `/behavior.xar`), i.e.

```
animation_player_service.run("animations/Stand/Gestures/ShowTablet_3",_async=True)
```

This is run in Linux, so the letter case matters.