# Pepper animations not working in simulation using python SDK

Tags: python, animation, pepper

This question is similar to [Naoqi pepper python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152010/naoqi-pepper-python-sdk)

But unfortunately the solution doesn't work. I have not capitalised animation and yet have the same problem still, have tried copying the exact path and all other solutions.

Do animations not work with the SDK in simulation? I am unable to test on the real robot due to COVID.

```
animation_player_service = self.session.service("ALAnimationPlayer")
animation_player_service.run("animations/Stand/Gestures/ShowTablet_3")
```

Running on linux, can't find out how to access simulated robot shell (all research has suggested this isn't possible?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtual robot does not have any applications (pre)installled, thus even no `animations`. The only application running, when you use Choregraphe, is `.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior`. If you want to use `ALAnimationPlayer` to run an animation in the virtual robot, you can:

- create a new (extra) behavior with the animation in your application. This behavior can be named e.g. `anim`. It can contain e.g. the `Happy` box for Pepper.
- refer to the `anim` behavior in the PythonScript (in the default behavior):

```
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)
        self.anim = ALProxy('ALAnimationPlayer')

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        self.anim.run(".lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior/anim")
        self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
```